# How do I render pipe_tables with pandoc?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I manage to generate simple_tables tables presented in the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546547/how-do-i-specify-tables-in-my-markdown-document-using-pandoc-syntax). But when I copy-paste the markdown for pipe_tables [presented on johnmacfarlane.net](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html), it doesn't render as a table.

Comment: Did you turn on the `pipe_tables` extension?

Comment: I tried to but I get an `Unknown reader: markdown+pipe_tables`
exception. According to [this pandoc issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/751), it may be due to my version of pandoc 1.9.4.2.

Comment: The latest version is pandoc 1.13.2. Try updating and report back if that doesn't help.

Comment: @xmojmr and how does one do that??

Comment: @drevicko `pandoc -f markdown+pipe_tables input_file`